# Trying to add Go Back Function. (Previous) Button to my Multi Steps Form using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add Back buton to my existing Script without success so far. I like this script because it also has a Validation process. I tried another code that has Previous button working, but no validation which made my project useless..
Here is my Javascript code below:

```
                <script>
            //Validation & Steps
            $(document).ready(function () 
            {

            var navListItems = $('div.setup-panel div a');
            allWells = $('.setup-content');
            allNextBtn = $('.nextBtn');
            allPrevBtn = $('.prevBtn');
            allWells.hide();

            navListItems.click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $target = $($(this).attr('href'));
            $item = $(this);

            if (!$item.hasClass('disabled')) {
            navListItems.removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-default');
            $item.addClass('btn-success');
            allWells.hide();
            $target.show();
            $target.find('input:eq(0)').focus();
            }
            });

            allNextBtn.click(function () 
            {
            var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content");
            curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id");
            nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + 
   '"]').parent().next().children("a");
            curInputs =  curStep.find("input[type='url'],input[type='checkbox'],input[type='text'],input[type='email'],input[type='radio']"); //
            isValid = true;

            $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
            for (var i = 0; i < curInputs.length; i++) 
            {
            if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid) 
            {
            isValid = false;
            $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
            }
            }

            if (isValid) nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');

            });
            // Back button click action
            allPrevBtn.click(function()
            {
            curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id");
            curStep = curStep - 2;
            allPrevBtn.trigger('click');
            nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click'); 
            allWells.hide();

            })  


            $('div.setup-panel div a.btn-success').trigger('click');
            });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was returned to source of your code, this is full code with back button:

```
<html >
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <style>
        body{
            margin-top:40px;
        }

        .stepwizard-step p {
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        .stepwizard-row {
            display: table-row;
        }

        .stepwizard {
            display: table;
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
        }

        .stepwizard-step button[disabled] {
            opacity: 1 !important;
            filter: alpha(opacity=100) !important;
        }

        .stepwizard-row:before {
            top: 14px;
            bottom: 0;
            position: absolute;
            content: " ";
            width: 100%;
            height: 1px;
            background-color: #ccc;
            z-order: 0;

        }

        .stepwizard-step {
            display: table-cell;
            text-align: center;
            position: relative;
        }

        .btn-circle {
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 6px 0;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 1.428571429;
            border-radius: 15px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var navListItems = $('div.setup-panel div a'),
                allWells = $('.setup-content'),
                allNextBtn = $('.nextBtn'),
                allPrevBtn = $('.prevBtn');


            allWells.hide();

            navListItems.click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
                    $item = $(this);

                if (!$item.hasClass('disabled')) {
                    navListItems.removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
                    $item.addClass('btn-primary');
                    allWells.hide();
                    $target.show();
                    $target.find('input:eq(0)').focus();
                }
            });

            allNextBtn.click(function(){
                var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
                    curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
                    nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
                    curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url']"),
                    isValid = true;

                $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
                for(var i=0; i<curInputs.length; i++){
                    if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid){
                        isValid = false;
                        $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
                    }
                }

                if (isValid)
                    nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
            });

            allPrevBtn.click(function(){
                var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
                    curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
                    prevStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().prev().children("a");
                    prevStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
            });


            $('div.setup-panel div a.btn-primary').trigger('click');
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="stepwizard">
        <div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel">
            <div class="stepwizard-step">
                <a href="#step-1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">1</a>
                <p>Step 1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="stepwizard-step">
                <a href="#step-2" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">2</a>
                <p>Step 2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="stepwizard-step">
                <a href="#step-3" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">3</a>
                <p>Step 3</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form role="form">
        <div class="row setup-content" id="step-1">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h3> Step 1</h3>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
                        <input  maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name"  />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
                        <input maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name" />
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" >Next</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row setup-content" id="step-2">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h3> Step 2</h3>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>
                        <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Company Address</label>
                        <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Address"  />
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-warning prevBtn btn-lg pull-left" type="button" >Back</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" >Next</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row setup-content" id="step-3">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h3> Step 3</h3>
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right" type="submit">Finish!</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```